# Spring internationalization works from xml config but not from Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Spring internationalization works from xml config but not from Java Config.

here are the files i have setup. I am not sure what else is required.
followed steps suggested:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-localeresolver
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-config-interceptors

springconfig.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pavan" />

    <annotation-driven />
<!-- 
    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="siteLanguage" />
        </beans:bean>
    </interceptors> -->

</beans:beans>
```

WebConfig

```
package com.pavan.web.spring.configs;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

      @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
        }

       @Bean
        public ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
            ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource slr = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
            slr.setBasename("classpath:messages");
            return slr;
        }

       @Bean
        public ViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
            bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return bean;
        }


        @Bean
        public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
            CookieLocaleResolver slr = new CookieLocaleResolver();
            slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
            slr.setCookieMaxAge(1000); 
            slr.setCookieName("myAppLocaleCookie");
            return slr;
        }

        @Bean
        public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
            LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
            lci.setParamName("locale");
            return lci;
        }

        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {         
            registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());         
        }


}


package com.pavan.spring;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        return "home";
    }

}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ page session="false"%>
<html>
<head>
<title><spring:message code="label.title" /></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="login">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label> <strong><spring:message
                                code="label.firstName" /></strong>
                </label></td>
                <td><input name="firstName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label> <strong><spring:message
                                code="label.lastName" /></strong>
                </label></td>
                <td><input name="lastName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <spring:message code="label.submit" var="labelSubmit"></spring:message>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="${labelSubmit}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

messages_en.properties
label.title=Login Page
label.firstName=First Name
label.lastName=Last Name
label.submit=Login

messages_fr.properties
label.title=Connectez-vous page
label.firstName=Pr\u00E9nom
label.lastName=Nom
label.submit=Connexion
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because of `@ComponentScan` . Can you try with component scan in java config if it is not added .

https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06s02.html

Comment: that's not the case, i have tried and it, that did not help. and also you can see all beans registered in the class are configured as it got @Configuration , for e.g it takes to jsp page

Comment: Assuming you have used @ComponentScan("com.pavan") , what did not work ? Any exception or it didnt log the expected locale or anything else ?

Comment: yes i have added @ComponentScan("com.pavan") and it did not help,  i did set some debug points to check what is happening. and noticed the following behavior .

Comment: more info: yes i have added @ComponentScan("com.pavan"), it did not help. I did set some break points to debug and noticed the following behavior. these are in APIs break point at HandlerExecutionChain applyPreHandle method and it does not show the interceptor i have added for the url /spring-basic/hello, however i have an image loaded on the same jsp file and it does shows the interceptor in list, still the parameter lang is set with null for image further in the chain at LocaleChangeInterceptor preHandle method. but all these are coming good when i switch back to xml config

Comment: This is crazy . If this is in github . Can you provide me a link .

Comment: i have added it here https://github.com/gcpavanpatil/spring-locale

Answer (score 0):

i have solved this by removing this and it has started working without it.

```
<annotation-driven />, it seems this was conflicting with the @Configuration
```

and failing.